# Actuator endpoints not exposed via HTTP in Spring boot 1.5.2 version in same port as application is running

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am using springboot version 1.5.2.RELEASE and i tried to implement spring boot actuator in my application. I am running my application in port 8081 . I just want to expose two end points i.e health and info. When i try to access end points in port 8081 same as my application, it does not gives the result and shows 404 not found status in Postman. I can access the health end point in port 8089 as http://localhost:8089/admin/info. Same thing i could not achieve in port 8081. I have searched for the answer and could not find proper answer for spring boot version 1.5.2.
 My application.yml file looks like this:

```
management:
  context-path : /admin
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: health,info
    jmx:
      exposure:
        exclude: '*'
  security:
    enabled: true
  port: 8081
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have your `management.port` set to `8089`, then you will only be able to access the management APIs at that port. You will not be able to reach them at the application port `8081`

If you would like to reach the management APIs at the application port, do not set the `managment.port` value. It defaults to the same port as the application port.

Comment: i have already tried that before by removing line managment.port:8089 and I am not able to access endpoint in 8081.

Comment: i can access my application from port 8081

Comment: I even tried to set management.port =8081. It is still not working.